# Powershell: Parse Log file case sensitive

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and i need help on a really simple script.
I've got a big log file (100 M) which i want to parse and return errors and warning messages.
Here is the format of the log file:

2013-04-18T10:38:04,110 **INFO**  [00002865] 30:toto.toto - WARNING: La variable sousdomn existe déjà pour le fichier WORK.RGPDROITS.

The aim is to check the bold value (which could be WARN ; ERROR ; INFO) and return lines where the bold value is "WARN" or "ERROR"

Here is the script tested on the WARN value:

```
$logfile = "C:\log\logfile.log" 
cat $logfile |
Select-String -pattern WARN -CaseSensitive|
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
            write-output $_.
            }
```

Unfortunately, it also returns "INFO" messages when they contain the string WARNING:

2013-04-18T10:38:04,141 INFO  [00002865] 30:toto.toto - WARNING: Référence symbolique apparente NBPERA non traitée.

I think, i need to use something like the -clike option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your pattern with:

```
Select-String -Pattern "\sWARN\s"
```

`\s` is for space. You can use a regular expression in pattern string

Comment: You do not need to thanks, just mark answer as useful (up arrow) or as answer

Answer (score 0):

In above code pattern WARN will catch string "WARNING" so you need to add extra space \s in regular expression to avoid WARNING so correct code will be

```
$logfile = "C:\log\logfile.log";
cat $logfile |
Select-String -pattern WARN\s -CaseSensitive|
  select -expand line |
    foreach {
      write-output $_.
    }
```